# How to get JSON or JSONP results cross-origin from the visistat.com API using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain, asp.net-web-api

I am using the following API call in jQuery to retrieve data. I've appended `?callback=?` at the end which seems to get around the cross origin domain issue, if I don't include that I get the cross domain error.

In chrome it says, *"Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type `text/html`."*

The response returned is `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`.

I can see the response by looking at it in Chrome *Console* → *Resources*. But how can I manipulate the response in JavaScript?

```
$.getJSON("http://api.visistat.com/stats-api-v2.php?key=skx79q0pyu01.&qt=idd&d=json&sdate=2012-08-26&edate=2012-08-28?callback=?", function(json) {
    console.log(json);
});
```

I do not have access to change the API.

**Update:**
Trying to work around using YQL e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/4VEHR/5/

Looks like this plugin may also be useful: https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/

Comment: That API link doesn't work for me. I think it has some kind of cookie it checks to verify you're allowed to see it. But try using [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql) as a proxy - it can read JSON and return JSONP or CORS.

Comment: Sorry yeah a direct link to that page doesn't work, to see it go to the website, then click "live demo" then "statcaster API".

Thanks for the YQL suggestion I think I am making some progress here goo.gl/6k5Tg

Comment: I'm having no luck at all finding any documentation for their API. What values besides `JSON` can the `d` parameter take? I tried `XML` or just leaving it out but got various errors. One quirk with YQL is that though it can input and output JSON, internally everything is XML and the converting between formats can make them a little "weird". Perhaps you can use the `d` parameter to get a more straightforward data format through YQL.

Comment: Aha I found the docs. Notice you can choose other output formats, all flat text files using various delimiters, comma is the most common as in `CSV` format: `select * from csv where url="http://api.visistat.com/stats-api-v2.php?key=skx79q0pyu01.&qt=idd&d=comma&sdate=2012-08-26&edate=2012-08-28"` - notice that one field has a strange value `<?=$e?>` in some formats and empty string in another format. This might be a bug or some quirk you'll need to work around?

Comment: Thanks pulling the data in CSV format helped me get it in a much nicer format to work with. Yeah looks like the data is a bit weird sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have control over `api.visistat.com` and can modify the `stats-api-v2.php` script, there is nothing you can do besides contacting the service and asking them to fix the headers they send with the response (it needs `Content-Type: text/json`, while the PHP default is `text/html`). On the browser side, the warning you get occurs before Javascript has had any chance to work with the data — jQuery instantiates a `<script>` element with your API URL as its source, and the browser notices the content type mismatch immediately when the response is received, before passing it back to jQuery.

This warning is harmless, though. The real problem is that the service you're using does not support JSONP — you provide the `callback` parameter as specified in the jQuery documentation to force JSONP result expectation, but the service does not actually produce valid JSONP (it still produces plain JSON). I've tried changing `d=json` to `d=jsonp` in your API request, but apparently it is not supported by the service. You will need to figure out a way to get JSONP result from the service, or implement a server-side proxy on your domain, to the avoid cross-domain issues.

Comment: This makes sense, although I can't understand why it would not be possible to work with a text/html response through some work around given the browser is receiving the data. 

If I implement something server side won't I still have the same issue trying to manipulate the returned text/html data with javascript? I guess the idea is parse it first to be jsonp like.

The link to the api page is http://www.visistat.com/tracking/api-manager.php

Comment: server side proxy is the only option if you can't have access to change the api. In that case you can send whatever you want as response headers...

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try using node.

Comment: You're getting a valid JSON response, though with a wrong `Content-Type: text/html` header. The wrong header _is not_ the problem here — the problem is that you're getting a JSON response, which would only work with same-origin content. You're making a cross-domain request, so you need JSONP instead of JSON, which the service you're using apparently does not support. Even if you somehow work around the wrong `Content-Type` you're receiving, this will not change the situation at all, because you would still be receiving JSON data instead of JSONP.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I am making some progress using YQL. I believe this is now JSONP? and I just need to sort out the callback in my code?

see here http://goo.gl/6k5Tg

Comment: Yes, this request returns proper JSONP. You shouldn't need to worry about the callback, jQuery should take care about it: [example](http://jsbin.com/isovup/1/edit)

Comment: If you're using YQL it supports CORS as well as JSONP, so unless you need to support older browsers CORS is generally better than JSONP.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I will look at using CORS instead of JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

Use $.ajax like this

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://api.visistat.com/stats-api-v2.php?key=skx79q0pyu01.&qt=idd&d=json&sdate=2012-08-26&edate=2012-08-28",
    dataType:'jsonp',
    crossDomain:true,
    success:function(data){alert(data);}
})​;​
```

Comment: Won't work because of cross-domain restrictions. Seems that there is no way to use that API using only Javascript.

Comment: Still does not fix the problem. The server needs to send the right headers. (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) `$.getJson` is just a short for `$.ajax` with some configurations but does the same thing.

Comment: here 's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/4VEHR/) of it not working (like I said. It can't work because of the missing header)

Answer (score 0):

If you use that `callback` parameter you tell jquery to use jsonP

This means your response should be wrapped with:

```
callback( ...your data...);
```

JSONP means it creates a method `callback` (that can fetch the data). Than adds a scripttag with src attribute your url. the script gets loaded the callback method executed. You have the data.

If you can't access/change the api to fix this you can't use jsonP.

You speak of CORS. That's a different story... You just have to make sure it's sending the right headers.

http://enable-cors.org/

Basically make sure it sends `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your domain`
(or * to allow all)

If you can't do that your only option is a proxy. A proxy is a sort of middleware. You make a request to the script the script gets the data, and returns it to you. For example [php proxy](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.de/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html). You can make the same thing in asp, jsp, flash or even java applet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I will need to look further into using a proxy. I am getting data back in text/html form so thought there must be some way to manipulate that, but sounds like it's not possible.

Comment: the text/html is least of your problems :) And you can modify them in your proxy anyway.

Comment: Trying to work around this using YQL see here, I think this is now valid JSONP? goo.gl/6k5Tg

Comment: yup that can work. you can set the diagnostics to false (won't need that) and you probably can make your output a little nicer (less json json json) if you adapt the query but this will already work.